# How to force signal, so value is changed after release?

Tags: vhdl

For test purpose, I use the VHDL feature `force`.

This changes the current value of the signal.
However, the change only lasts while the `force` is applied, unless the process that usually controls the signal does an assign.

Is there any way to make the `force` apply to the saved signal, thus also after `release`?

Example of waveform is shown below, where the design updates the alpha_value at every 1 us tick.
[image]

At 0.5 us, it shows that the alpha_value change goes back from 13 to 0 after `release`.  At 2.5 us, it shows that the internal alpha_value is changed to 42 at 2.0 us, so the alpha_value returns to 42 at `release`.

Example code is:

```
entity mdl is
  port(clk : in  boolean; alpha_out : out natural);
end entity;

architecture rtl of mdl is  -- Module with alpha_value/out update every microsecond
  signal cntr         : natural := 0;
  signal alpha_value  : natural := 0;
  signal alpha_update : natural := 0;  -- Increments at each update of alpha_value
begin
  process (clk) is
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      cntr <= cntr + 1;
      if cntr = 99 then  -- At microsecond tick, so time to increment alpha
        cntr         <= 0;
        alpha_value  <= alpha_value + 1;
        alpha_update <= alpha_update + 1;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
  alpha_out <= alpha_value;
end architecture;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture sim of tb is
  signal clk                                           : boolean := true;  -- Clock for mdl
  alias alpha_value is << signal .tb.mdl_e.alpha_value : natural >>;       -- mdl internal alpha_value
  signal alpha_out                                     : natural;          -- Output from module
  signal alpha_force                                   : boolean;          -- Shows when force to alpha_value is applied
begin

  -- Clock generate at 100 MHz, thus 100 ticks per microsecond
  clk <= not clk after 5 ns;

  -- Module
  mdl_e : entity work.mdl port map (clk => clk, alpha_out => alpha_out);

  -- Force process in test bench
  process is
  begin
    -- Force between increment
    wait for 0.3 us;
    alpha_value <= force 13;  -- From 0.3 us to 0.5 us
    alpha_force <= true;
    wait for 0.2 us;
    alpha_value <= release;
    alpha_force <= false;
    -- Force over increment
    wait for 1.0 us;
    alpha_value <= force 41;  -- From 1.5 us to 2.5 us
    alpha_force <= true;
    wait for 1.0 us;
    alpha_value <= release;
    alpha_force <= false;
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture;
```

---

**Update at 2023-11-07**: Below code is the original example code, what was made too short to show the problem in a realistic setting.  The example code above has thus been created, to show a realistic setting for apply of force.

```
entity tb is
end entity;

architecture sim of tb is

  signal alpha_value  : natural;
  signal alpha_update : natural;  -- Increments at each update of alpha_value
  signal alpha_force  : boolean;  -- Shows when force to alpha_value is applied

begin

  -- Update process
  process is
  begin
    while true loop
      wait for 1.0 us;
      alpha_value  <= alpha_value + 1;
      alpha_update <= alpha_update + 1;
    end loop;
  end process;

  -- Force process
  process is
  begin
    -- Force between increment
    wait for 0.3 us;
    alpha_value <= force 13;  -- From 1 to 2 us
    alpha_force <= true;
    wait for 0.2 us;
    alpha_value <= release;
    alpha_force <= false;
    -- Force over increment
    wait for 1.0 us;
    alpha_value <= force 41;  -- From 5 to 7 us
    alpha_force <= true;
    wait for 1.0 us;
    alpha_value <= release;
    alpha_force <= false;
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: Im not quite sure what you're trying to do here. Force and release are there to specically override other drivers on a signal. When you `release`, you are handing back control to the other drivers. What value are you expecting or wanting to leave ong `alfa_value` after release? do you really need to `force` and `release`? you would usually do all stimulus from a single process.

Comment: The example is a simplification from the actual problem.  In that, I have a 16 bit counter where I must test wrapping from all 1's to all 0's.  So I want to make the test bench change the value of the counter to e.g. 0xFFFD, and then let the regular design update the counter afterwards.  The test will then be able to read the count value, and check that the wrapping occurs correctly.  For that purpose I need the change applied by `force` to update the actual value of the counter, and not just override the perceived value while the `force` is in effect.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, what you would need to do is force the input to your counter register so that the value is persisted inside your counter after release.
You can do so using VHDL2008 external names. They allow you to "grab" and force signals anywhere in your design not only in the testbench.

Comment: @rhall but that still leaves the problem the OP has. On release, the value goes back to the original driver. So while you may force 0xFFFD, the process inside the DUT might still be driving 0.

Comment: @rhall: The original code that triggered creation of the question did use external name, like `<< signal alpha_value : natural >>`, but was removed as part of the simplification.  As @Tricky points out, the external name gives hierarchal access, but the problem with non-persistent change remains.

Comment: Okay, i need to take lessons in reading comprehension. I'm still not sure about your goals here. But I think there are two separate issues that need to be addressed. First: After you release, the only way for the forced value to be saved is if some other part of the design has seen that value and stored it. So in your example you do need to time your force so that it is active during the counter change for the forced value to propagate

Comment: Second: In your example code, there is no way to force the input to the counter, since there is no target. If you split the counter in a combinatorial signal `alpha_input <= alpha_value + 1` and a clocked process which assigns the counter `alpha_value <= alpha_input` you'll be able to force the input of your counter by applying the force on `alpha_input`. You'll still need to time the force correctly, but you'll store the value you forced in the counter.

Comment: In 'original example code' note [LCS2016_I05](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/LCS2016_I05), passed, correcting an example error in the -2019 LRM to show an alias declaration illegal. Here the alias can't be declared before the instantiation statement for mdl_e. What the external name simple object name refers to can't be determined until the instantiation is elaborated. The alias can be a process declarative item. here. Which VHDL tool accepted your code?  A recent mcode version of ghdl does not, "CONSTRAINT_ERROR : elab-vhdl_context.adb:509 discriminant check failed".

Comment: See [VHDL 2008 can't drive a signal with an alias of an external name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347200/vhdl-2008-cant-drive-a-signal-with-an-alias-of-an-external-name) where the error wasn't provided. Should be vsim-3043 "The specified name in a simple or hierarchical reference cannot be found as an instance or object in the design. If the reference is a VHDL external name one possible reason the reference cannot be found is the instance has not been elaborated yet. Aliases to external names cannot occur in the declarative region that the instance being searched for occurs."

Comment: @user16145658: Thanks for the reference; I will take a look at that :-)

Comment: Will you identify the VHDL simulator and version that allowed you to declare the aliases as block declarative items?

Comment: @user16145658: Sure, the Aldec Riviera-PRO 2023.10 was used, with compile option for VHDL 2008 (`-2008`).  Is there some VHDL construction that should not be allowed ?

Comment: There's the elaboration order issue between the alias declaration and the instantiation of mdl_e, which hasn't been completed when the alias is elaborated. The external path and object simple name for the target of the alias are not defined when the alias as a block declarative item is elaborated. That is not the case for declaring the alias as a process declarative item when the process statement follows the instantiation, 14.4.1, 14.2, 14.4.2.6  and vsim-3043 which shows Modelsim enforces the requirement. It's a portability issue even if it works.

Comment: Your newer example code with the mdl instantiation using the reserved word entity doesn't match your previously published waveform image. The signal alpha_update is not incremented in tb.

Comment: @user16145658: Thanks for noticing; yes, the alpha_update should also be moved to mdl to have identical behavior; I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach found is to make the force take effect each clock cycle, which is possible by adding a alpha_value signal self assign in mdl module with:

```
  process (clk) is
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      alpha_value <= alpha_value;  -- Update to make force in test take effect each cycle
      ...
```

The internal value is thereby updated with the `force` value at the rising clock, so the resulting waveforms will be:

[image]

The forced signal is thereby changed after release if at least a single clock cycle has passed.  This can be ensured by applying the `force` for a short time, without having to consider how this short time is synchronized to the 1 us update period.

Comment: While a self assignment is the only was to effectuate a 0 for alpha_value there is at least [one other way to force your 13 value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnHU4.jpg) without modifying external block mdl (entities and architectures are elaborated into nested block statements). It requires multiple clocks and forcing cntr as well. I bundled this into a procedure defined as a process declarative item. Note that with the ability to force a natural range alpha_value it should roll over for simulation purposes.